# Can't upgrade themes or plugins after upgrading WordPress to 4.4

Tags: plugins, upgrade

I just upgraded a site to WordPress version 4.4, and now whenever I try to upgrade any plugin or theme I get a message like this:

```
An error occurred while updating <plugin/theme name>: Could not create directory. <plugin/theme directory>
```

I have set the permission on the `wp-content` directory (and even all subdirectories) to 777, but I still get the above message whenever I try to upgrade a plugin or theme.

What gives?

I **am** able to install new plugins, so it doesn't seem to be a permission issue in the plugins folder.

More research:

In `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-uploader.php`, lines 531-535:

```
//Create destination if needed
if ( ! $wp_filesystem->exists( $remote_destination ) ) {
    if ( ! $wp_filesystem->mkdir( $remote_destination, FS_CHMOD_DIR ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'mkdir_failed_destination', $this->strings['mkdir_failed'], $remote_destination );
    }
}
```

The exists call is returning false when I try to update a plugin. This is wrong. I am able to see the directory referred to by `$remote_destination` in my OS shell, and it obviously does exist because the failure occurs on the mkdir call—it is unable to make the directory because it already exists.

Digging deeper, in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php`, lines 329-338:

```
public function exists( $file ) {
    $path = dirname( $file );
    $filename = basename( $file );    

    $file_list = @ftp_nlist( $this->link, '-a ' . $path );
    if ( $file_list ) {
        $file_list = array_map( 'basename', $file_list );
    }
    return $file_list && in_array( $filename, $file_list );
}
```

If I add the following line just before the return statement...

```
error_log(debug_backtrace()[1]['function'] . ": \npath: $path\nfilename: $filename\nfile list:\n" . print_r($file_list, true) . "\n");
```

... I see this output for the relevant call ...

```
[11-Dec-2015 18:42:19 UTC] install_package:
path: <the expected path>
filename: <the expected filename>
file list: 
Array
(
)
```

The file list is empty! It should not be. What's going on here?

Comment: As an additional note: I have verified that reverting my WordPress install to 4.3 fixes this issue, and I am able to upgrade plugins and themes just fine.

Comment: This is a [WP bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34976).

Answer (score -1):

In file `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php`, line 333:

Replace

```
$file_list = @ftp_nlist( $this->link, '-a ' . $path );
```

With

```
$file_list = @ftp_nlist( $this->link, $path );
```

Comment: This isn't really an acceptable answer. If you modify core files such as this they will be overwritten whenever WordPress upgrades. Never a good idea to modify core.